# Semáforos podem impedir deadlock?

Tags: sistemas-distribuídos

Caiu na minha prova de Sistemas Operacionais a seguinte pergunta: "Semáforos impedem que ocorra um deadlock"?
Pelo que eu havia estudado, acreditava que a resposta fosse "SIM". Porém na devolução da prova, o professor simplesmente escreveu "ERRADO!", mas não justificou.
Alguém poderia me explicar o porquê?

Comment: Bem, semáforos pode ser usados para *evitar* deadlock, mas não *impedem* https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/artofasm/CH19/CH19-15.html